# AWS Design- Do some flow after DB creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I need to run some scripts after RDS Creation in AWS.
Which service can I use to get a notification about DB creation is finished.
In fact, I need to run some jobs when there is new DB in RDS.

Comment: See options at [Using Amazon RDS event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html).